# Subdata (substring-like?) of a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I have a data buffer stored in a `shared_ptr<void>`.

This buffer is organized in several encapsulated layers so that I end up with:

```
-----------------------------------...
- Header 1 | Header 2 | Data
-----------------------------------...
```

(Actually it's an Ethernet packet where I decapsulate the layers one after the other).

Once I read Header 1, I would like to pass the rest of the packet to the next layer for reading, so I would like to create a pointer to :

```
-----------------------...
- Header 2 | Data
-----------------------...
```

It would be very easy with a raw pointer, as it would just be a matter of pointer arithmetic. But how can I achieve that with a shared_ptr ? (I use boost::shared_ptr) :

- I cannot create a new shared_ptr to "first shared_ptr.get() + offset" because it makes no sense to get the ownership to just `Header 2 + Data` (and delete would crash eventually)
- I do not want to copy the data because it would be silly
- I want the ownership on the **whole** buffer to be shared between the two objects (ie. as long as the parent object or the one which requires only Header 2 needs the data, the data should not be deleted).

I could wrap that up in a structure like `boost::tuple<shared_ptr<void>, int /*offset*/, int /*length*/>` but I wonder if there is a more convenient / elegant way to achieve that result.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, I just used a simple wrapper that I reproduce here if someone ever stumbles on the question.

```c
class DataWrapper {
public:
    DataWrapper (shared_ptr<void> pData, size_t offset, size_t length) : mpData(pData), mOffset(offset), mLength(length) {}

    void* GetData() {return (unsigned char*)mpData.get() + mOffset;}
    // same with const...
    void SkipData (size_t skipSize) { mOffset += skipSize; mLength -= skipSize; }
    void GetLength const {return mLength;}

    // Then you can add operator+, +=, (void*), -, -=
    // if you need pointer-like semantics.
    // Also a "memcpy" member function to copy just this buffer may be useful
    // and other helper functions if you need

private:
    shared_ptr<void> mpData;
    size_t mOffset, mLength;
};
```

Just be careful when you use GetData: be sure that the buffer will not be freed while you use the unsafe void*. It is safe to use the void* as long as you know the DataWrapper object is alive (because it holds a shared_ptr to the buffer, so it prevents it from being freed).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend encapsulating the layers each in a class that knows how to deal with the data as though it were that layer. Think each one as a view into your buffer. Here is a starting point to get you thinking.

```
class Layer1{
public:
    Layer1(shared_ptr<void> buffer) : buffer_(buffer) { }

   /* All the functions you need for treating your buffer as a Layer 1 type */
    void DoSomething() {}

private:
   shared_ptr<void> buffer_;
};

class Layer2{
public:
    Layer2(shared_ptr<void> buffer) : buffer_(buffer) { }

   /* All the functions you need for treating your buffer as a Layer 2 type */
    void DoSomethingElse() {}

private:
   shared_ptr<void> buffer_;
};
```

And how to use it:

```
shared_ptr<void> buff = getBuff(); //< Do what you need to get the raw buffer.

// I show these together, but chances are, sections of your code will only need
// to think about the data as though it belongs to one layer or the other.
Layer1 l1(buff);
Layer2 l2(buff);

l1.DoSomething();
l2.DoSomethingElse();
```

Laying things out this way allows you to write functions that operate solely on that layer even though they internally represent the same data.

But, *this is by no means perfect.*

Perhaps Layer2 should be able to call Layer1's methods. For that you would want inheritance as well. I don't know enough about your design to say whether that would be helpful. Other room for improvement is replacing the `shared_ptr<void>` with a class that has helpful methods for dealing with the buffer.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is: Layer2 does not know (if we don't tell it) what is header 1 length (and shouldn't care). It should just see the buffer starting from Header 2, you know what I mean. So either I exchange some data between layer 1 and layer 2 (e.g. the offset to skip), or the pointer given to layer 2 is already offset somehow.

Actually, I just want something like string::substr!!

Comment: @Mic Ok, I'd definitely lean toward factoring out the `shared_ptr<void>` into something smarter that can keep track of where in the buffer each layer starts. `Layer1` and `Layer2` can hold a shared_ptr to that object instead.
It seems like you want to have separate types for each layer and at the same time have code that operates specifically on a single layer. I think this approach grants both of those.

Comment: Yeah, so both layers keep the same shared_ptr, and use an "offset" variable to get the pointer, like : smart.get() + offset. But it's anti-idiomatic since it uses void* and doesn't have the guarantee of lifetime. But I agree with you, I'll go down this way. Was just checking if there was some magic stuff I didn't know about.

Comment: You are guaranteed that lifetime at least encompasses the scope of the shared pointer which is why each level holds onto one. Provided that nobody outside the class holds a raw pointer (and they shouldn't because it is private) you are safe. I agree that calling get() on a shared_ptr hurts a little, my concern was containing the need to do it in a safe[er] way.

Answer (score 0):

can you just use a simple wrapper?

something like this maybe?

```
class HeaderHolder : protected shared_ptr<void> {
public:
    // Constructor and blah blah

    void* operator* () {
        offset += a_certain_length;
        return (shared_ptr<void>::operator*() + offset);
    }
};
```

Comment: Well, operator* would return a reference to `void` here, so not applicable. Still, I get your point, it's the idea of storing an offset somehow (as tuple as I said, or in a derived object as you mention. I like the idea of not intruding into the boost hierarchy better though, so I would rather avoid deriving from shared_ptr).